# Start app/command-line tool without internet/network access

Tags: internet, macos, malware

Is there anything that can help me launch an app or command-line tool without internet or network access even when I'm connected to the internet? (so that I can use other apps with Internet, and block access for some apps) Like a firewall? Or something that intercepts the syscalls, something like [maybe](https://github.com/p-e-w/maybe)?

Comment: All applications and command line tools (e.g. TextEdit.app, `cp`) can start without Internet access. However, the github link seems to simulate the `--dry-run` option on `rsync`, but your question asks for "starting things while not connected to the Internet". You may wish to edit your question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry Done.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you're looking for would be Little Snitch. You can find out more about it and download it [here](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).